# How to pass sympy expressions to be used with scipy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sympy, scipy-optimize

I want to solve a systen of non-linear equations created by loops using **root** from `scipy.optimize`. I want to create the equations with one method and then solve them with another. I created the equations with **sympy** and want to solve them with scipy. My real code has too many loops and every time **root** from scipy iterates those loops.

This is a very simplified version of what I tried. I made the equations with **sympy** symbols and then I used `lambdify` to take the equations out of **sympy** but the solver sends me an error.

```py
from scipy.optimize import root
from sympy import Symbol, lambdify

y = [Symbol('x%d' % i) for i in range(2)]

def ecuacion():

    global c,cakeo,mellado

    c = []
    cakeo = y[0] +1 + y[1]
    c.append(cakeo)
    mellado = y[1] + 4 + -y[0]
    c.append(mellado)
    print(c)
    return c

ecuacion()

f = lambdify(y, c, 'numpy')

def solver():

    Guess = [1,-1]
    sol = root(f, Guess,method='hybr', jac=False) # Entrega el resultado       
    print(sol.x)
    return sol

solver()
```

It sends me this error **TypeError: root() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jac'.**
If I delete jac, it send sme this TypeError: unsupported operand **type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'**

**these are the tracebacks with jac**

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/gian_/Documents/Irri-trickle/speed/i.py', wdir='C:/Users/gian_/Documents/Irri-trickle/speed')

File "C:\Users\gian_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\gian_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/gian_/Documents/Irri-trickle/speed/i.py", line 54, in 
    solver()

File "C:/Users/gian_/Documents/Irri-trickle/speed/i.py", line 49, in solver
    sol = root(f, Guess, method='krylov')  # Entrega el resultado

TypeError: root() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jac'

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/gian_/Documents/Irri-trickle/speed/i.py', wdir='C:/Users/gian_/Documents/Irri-trickle/speed')

File "C:\Users\gian_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\gian_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/gian_/Documents/Irri-trickle/speed/i.py", line 54, in 
    solver()

File "C:/Users/gian_/Documents/Irri-trickle/speed/i.py", line 49, in solver
    sol = root(f, Guess, jac = False)  # Entrega el resultado

TypeError: root() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jac'

Comment: What error?  If you expect real help, then give us real information about your problem.

Comment: Recent SO about `lambdify`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738051/add-object-has-no-attribute-sinh-error-in-numerical-and-symbolic-expression; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58648617/float-object-has-no-attribute-sin; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465018/why-sympy-lambdify-function-cannot-identify-numpy-sum-function-and-multiply-func

Comment: Add your `imports` and `sympy` setup to the question.  Depending on the error we may want to run your case, and suggest working fixes.  Without that answers are likely to contain bugs.

Comment: thanks, i fixed it

Comment: According the `root` docs, `jac=False` should be ok, but the default is `jac=None`, which I think means the same thing.   We need the traceback as well, to better identify where the error occurs (it may be several layers down in the `root` call).

Comment: i added them, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided code also gave me an error: *TypeError: _lambdifygenerated() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y1'*. Replacing the declaration of`y` by `y = DeferredVector('y')` solved the problem, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576876/finding-roots-with-a-sympy-matrix]). Supposing you are using recent versions of sympy and scipy.

I don't understand the strange error message about jac, as you entered it just fine. Maybe you are inadvertently using `root` from another package?

Try importing it with an unambiguous name as in:

```py
from scipy.optimize import root as scipy_root
from sympy import Symbol, lambdify, DeferredVector

y = DeferredVector('y')
...

def solver():
    guess = [1,-1]
    sol = scipy_root(f, guess, method='hybr', jac=False) # Entrega el resultado
    print(sol.x)
    return sol
```